# How do I order by date desc when the date is appended MYSQL?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a field called Trip ID in my system. This TRIP ID has a date appended to the last part of it. I would like to make my select field display the TRIP ID with the most recent date at the top aka order by date desc

[image: order by]

although in my database I have an id column, I cannot order by Id desc because if i do this it will display the trip ID entered last which might be a trip id with a very very historic date.

How can I alter this code to achive what i want ?

```
 $resultSet = $mysqli->query("Select tripid from college order by date desc");
```

My DDL for Create Table

```
CREATE TABLE `college` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `lastentrytime` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `thedate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `ac` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `captain` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `firstofficer` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `examiner` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `safetyfirst` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `airport1` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `airport2` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `bk1` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `bk2` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `airport3` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `airport4` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `bk3` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `bk4` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `airport5` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `airport6` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `bk5` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `bk6` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `airport7` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `airport8` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `bk7` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `bk8` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `airport9` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `airport10` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `bk9` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `bk10` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `airport11` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `airport12` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `bk11` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `bk12` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `airport13` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `airport14` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `bk13` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `bk14` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `airport15` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `airport16` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `bk15` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `bk16` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `Sectors` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `dutyon` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `dutyoff` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `flt_hrs` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `flt_min` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `duty_hrs` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `duty_min` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tripid` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `dutyt` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Comment: Use 2 separate queries: 1 query for the most-recent entry at the top, the other for the rest, and concatenate with a `UNION ALL` operator: `SELECT TOP 1 t.TripId FROM tbl AS t ORDER BY t.Date DESC UNION ALL SELECT r.TripId FROM tbl AS r ORDER BY r.TripId` (your SQL syntax may vary - I forget exactly which OFFSET/LIMIT/TOP syntax MySQL uses)

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time, and string handling, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: @jarlh I am using mysql

Comment: Can't you fix the tables instead, i.e. put the date in a separate column?

Comment: @jarlh im not sure if thats ideal, the tripid should have a date on it as the last part.

Comment: @PrinceMawungwa You know the difference between surrogate-keys and natural-keys, right? So what's the story here?

Comment: @Dai im not too pro and don't know what that is sorry :(

Comment: Please post your `CREATE TABLE` DDL statements and the first 50 rows of your data so we can get a better feel for what's going on.

Comment: @Dai posted now

Comment: Your table _really_ needs normalizing...

Comment: @Dai probbaly haha, im fairly new to databases but im sure as time goes on, I will fine tune the tables etc.

Comment: can you confirrm that the date is always in the same position in the tripid? and the date format is consistent yyyy-mm-dd?

Comment: @TSCAmerica.com yes, the date is always in the same position and is consistent.

Comment: Then you can use SUBSTR().

Comment: "the tripid should have a date on it as the last part." Why? You could always have a separate date column, which makes this kind of thing easier. Then you append the date in a view or computed column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the  the `date` is always in the same position and is consistent, try this

```
   SELECT tripid 
    FROM college 
    ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(RIGHT(tripid, 10), '%Y-%m-%d') DESC
```

Comment: wow!! It works, thanks a bunch mate..I have loads to learn